# Replace the XML element's name with the value of an attribute anywhere

Tags: xslt

I have a working XSLT that replaces an element name with an attribute value only when the attribute is named "AttributeID".  It saves the original element name in a new attribute called StepClass but it only works at one level.

This XML:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="One">1</Value>
      <MultiValue AttributeID="Multi1">
        <Value>111</Value>
      </MultiValue>
    </Values>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Becomes this XML:

```
 <Products>
  <Product>
    <Values>
      <One StepClass="Value">1</One>
      <Multi1 StepClass="MultiValue">
        <Value>111</Value>
      </Multi1>
    </Values>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Change Values/Value value of AttributeID -->
  <!--  <xsl:template match="Values/Value|MultiValue|MetaData/Value">  This was working with 1 level -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@AttributeID]">
    <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
    <xsl:attribute name="StepClass">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    </xsl:attribute>      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->
  <xsl:template match="@AttributeID" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But fails as soon as the source XML has nested products.  I would like the substitution to work at any level.  What am I doing wrong here?

Nested XML:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Values>
      <Value AttributeID="One">1</Value>
      <MultiValue AttributeID="Multi1">
        <Value>111</Value>
      </MultiValue>
    </Values>
    <Product>
      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="Two">2</Value>
        <MultiValue AttributeID="Multi2">
          <Value>222</Value>
        </MultiValue>
      </Values>
    </Product>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Comment: What is the problem with result? See [XSLT demo here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtq2)

Comment: There must be a problem with my source file that I missed.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the link.  It really helped me find the issue which was a space in an attribute buried in the source file.  My apologies for wasting time but thanks again and for proving my XSLT was working.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

XSLT as depicted in the post works as expected.

Comment: Consider deleting your entire post and not leave such an answer. OPs can delete their own question.